# Symfony How to configure events in FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to implement FOS confirmation email.

My Administrator entity extends FOSUser entity:

```
app.profile_edit_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ProfileEditListener
        arguments: [@fos_user.mailer, @fos_user.util.token_generator, @router, @session, @security.token_storage]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

And config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: AppBundle\Entity\Group
    service:
        mailer: swiftmailer.mailer.strato
    from_email:
            address:        web****@gmail.com
            sender_name:    *****
    registration:
        confirmation:
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
            enabled: true
```

But the listener is not called (it does not appear in the dev called listeners list on symfony console).

Do you know how to activate it? Thanks